# Been confused about string constrained motion for a while

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, constrained-dynamics

Let's have a look at the following set up:

[image]

Suppose Block C is moving downwards with a velocity "u" and we are required to find the velocity of bead "v" . So what we were taught in class was since C has velocity "u" , the string AB also has the same velocity "u" . And "u" will be a component of velocity of bead "v" .
i.e. u=vcosθ or v = usecθ

But why can't we say the other way round? We can say as well that since "u" is the velocity that makes the bead move in the first place , "v" must be a component of "u" and it should be lesser than "u" .
i.e. v=ucosθ

I asked my teacher about it , he was saying something about "v" being the 'actual' velocity so we should take its component along AB, but I could not quite get him .

I am aware of solving the problem by obtaining a mathematical expression for the length of the string and then differentiating it to get the answer , but it does not seem to solve the confusion I have developed over here.

Comment: "The string AB also has the same velocity u" this is absolutely not correct. AB is rotating, BC is not.

Answer (score 2):

Your teacher is correct. The bead's actual velocity is horizontal. It makes sense to break that into components parallel and perpendicular to the string.

The beads actual velocity is not along the string, so it doesn't make sense to try to break the velocity along the string into separate components.

However, if, for example, the bead was not attached to the horizonal wire and therefore not constrained, it would move with velocity u directly towards B. In this situation you could break that velocity into horizonal and vertical components. The horizonal component would be:

vh = ucosθ

But note that this velocity, vh, is not equal to the velocity v in the original question. The constraint changes the way the bead moves.

What is the same in both situations is that the bead is moving in such a way that its distance to B is decreasing by the rate u.  In both situations, u is the component of its velocity parallel to the string. In the first situation the bead is moving at angle θ so u = vcosθ. In the second situation, the angle is zero, so the component parallel to the string is the total velocity.

Answer (score 2):

Let's have a look at a simpler example:
[image: pulley system]

Following your reasoning, the velocity of block W should be $2v\cos\theta$.

But that's incorrect. You can't simply add velocities like that.

**What happens physically then?**

The vertical components of velocities you are adding are *not* block W's velocity. The two strings actually apply a force on W which results in its movement.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you got why u = vcosθ.
Here you have to use the constraint that string is inextensible,
so velocity of c along the string(the rate at which block c will increase the length of string) should be same as velocity of bead along string(rate at which bead will decrease length of string)
Also here you have to understand component of v perpendicular to string will have no effect on its length and that there is no component of u perpendicular to string.